# Is it possible to create dynamic aggregate properties in entity framework code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first

Consider below one-to-many relationship between course and student:

```
    public class Course{
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public int HeadCount {get;set;} // count of students, registered to the course
       public double AvgScore {get;set;} // average score of all registered students
       public List<Student> Students{get;set;}
    }

    public class Student{
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public double Score {get;set;}
       public Course Course {get;set;}
    }

    public class SchoolContext : DbContext{
       public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasOne(_ => _.Course).WithMany(_ => _.Students);
       }
    }
```

The course has couple of aggregated properties, count and average.

Initially I thought I will update the aggregated properties every time a new student is added in controller like below

```
    public class StudentAddVM {
       public string Name {get;set;}
       public int CourseId {get;set;}
       public double Score {get;set;}
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudent(StudentAddVM postBody) {
       // _context is an object of SchoolContext
       if(await _context.Courses.FindAsync(postBody.CourseId) is Course course){
          Student student = new(){
             Name = postBody.Name,
             Score = postBody.Score,
             Course = course
          };
          _context.Students.Add(student);

          // Manual update
          course.AvgScore = (course.AvgScore * course.HeadCount) / (course.HeadCount + 1);
          course.HeadCount += 1;

          await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
          return Ok();
       }
       return BadRequest();
    }
```

But things start to get messy when I try to add more functionality like updating course and deleting students.

Is there a way to automatically calculate these properties when I query for Course?

Also, If I go with this, will I still be able to selectively include students but get aggregated properties to consider all students?

For example if I have 30 students per course in my DB, below endpoint should return HeadCounts as 30 but include details for top three scorers only.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Course>>> GetCourses() => await _context.Courses.Include(_=>_.Students.OrderByDescending(_=>_.Score).Take(3)).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: if it was me I would not store derived values unless they are "expensive" to calculate.  can you perhaps use readonly properties that return a value based upon a calculation or rows count?

Comment: @Jazb I forgot to include the details of why I decided to store them in first place, I've edited my question. basically, I'd like to query for selective records but still have aggregated properties based on complete dataset.